# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>'

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost

Hi i have script that i want to run on my localhost . the code in PHP , and when i run my localhost, it says

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bot/course.php on line 23

this is the code:

```
<?php

ob_start();

$API_KEY = '';
define('API_KEY',$API_KEY);
function bot($method,$datas=[]){
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".API_KEY."/".$method;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$datas);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch)){
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    }else{
        return json_decode($res);
    }
}

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$message = $update- >message;
$text = $message- >text;
$chat_id = $message- >chat- >id;


if ($text =='/start') {
    bot('sendMessage',[
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        'text'=> 'Welcome',
    ]);
}
```

Line 23 is $message, I really dont see any wrongs there ?

Comment: Try to remove the whitespaces from - > to ->.
You are attempting to access a property. But right now you are trying to substract from >text- Which is invalid PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this code of yours

```
$message = $update- >message;
$text = $message- >text;
$chat_id = $message- >chat- >id;
```

try

```
$message = $update->message;
$text = $message->text;
$chat_id = $message->chat->id;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I did what you said but it says 

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bot/course.php on line 23

Comment: Hi Maher. Your error implies that you are accessing a non-object, maybe it was an array. Try var_dump($message);die; and see it's property, probably you need $message[0]->text for that.